# Объясните пожалуйста, как добавлен элемент в TreeMap в следующем коде

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap, treeset

Объясните пожалуйста вот этот код:

```
TreeSet<Station> connectedStations = connections.get(station);
connectedStations.addAll(stations.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.equals(station)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Как этот код добавляет в `TreeMap<Station, TreeSet<Station>> connections` элемент(ы)?

На вход в метод `addConnection()` передается `ArrayList<Station> stations`, содержащий 2 объекта  `Fourth` и `Violet`.

Первый объект из `ArrayList` передается в `TreeMap` с ключем-объект , а значение создается пустой `TreeSet()`.

После выхода из итерации цикла `for` значение `TreeSet<Station> connectedStations` кажется, что никуда не передаются. Однако после исполнения этого кода объект  добавляется в связку ключ-значение в `connections` (key: Fourth -> value: Violet).

Пытался отследить изменения при выполнении кода через дебаггер в IJ Idea, но так и не понял.

[image: До и после исполнения кода]

```
import core.Line;
import core.Station;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StationIndex
{
    HashMap<Integer, Line> number2line;
    TreeSet<Station> stations;
    TreeMap<Station, TreeSet<Station>> connections;

    public StationIndex()
    {
        number2line = new HashMap<>();
        stations = new TreeSet<>();
        connections = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public void addStation(Station station)
    {
        stations.add(station);
    }

    public void addLine(Line line)
    {
        number2line.put(line.getNumber(), line);
    }

    public void addConnection(List<Station> stations)
    {
        for(Station station : stations)
        {
            if(!connections.containsKey(station)) {
                connections.put(station, new TreeSet<>());
            }
            TreeSet<Station> connectedStations = connections.get(station);
            connectedStations.addAll(stations.stream()
                .filter(s -> !s.equals(station)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }

    public Line getLine(int number)
    {
        return number2line.get(number);
    }

    public Station getStation(String name)
    {
        for(Station station : stations)
        {
            if(station.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return station;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Station getStation(String name, int lineNumber)
    {
        Station query = new Station(name, getLine(lineNumber));
        Station station = stations.ceiling(query);
        return station.equals(query) ? station : null;
    }

    public Set<Station> getConnectedStations(Station station)
    {
        if(connections.containsKey(station)) {
            return connections.get(station);
        }
        return new TreeSet<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что этот код создавая новый объект TreeSet<Station> присваивает ему ссылку на уже созданный объект TreeSet<Station>, который является value для TreeMap stations. 
А далее, так как ссылка в JVM connectedStations и value в TreeMap идет на один и тот же объект, то редактируя connectedStations, я изменяю содержимое value в TreeMap. Верно ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде бы в дебаггере всё понятно отображается, и в целом комментарий-уточнение под вопросом является верным. :)

Дебаггер находится внутри указанного метода `addConnection`.

Состояние "До" соответствует моменту на *второй итерации*, когда для `station = "Violet" (Station@1303)` был создан пустой `TreeSet` (TreeSet@1367, size=0), который был уже добавлен в мапу с ключом, равным текущему значению `station`.

Поэтому `connectedStations`, прочитанный по ключу `station="Violet"`, ссылается на ТОТ ЖЕ пустой экземпляр `TreeSet` (TreeSet@1367, size=0).

При выполнении строки:

```java
 connectedStations.addAll(stations.stream()
                .filter(s -> !s.equals(station)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

в "бывшее" пустое множество `connectedStations` добавляются *все* отфильтрованные элементы списка `stations`, НЕ равные текущему `station`, то есть добавляется список, включающий ПЕРВЫЙ элемент списка `Fourth`.  Соответственно, аналогичное изменение видно и в мапе `connections`.

В состоянии "После" цикла `for` локальная ссылка из цикла `connectedStations` УЖЕ не существует, но мапа-поле класса `connections` содержит `Map.Entry` с ключом `"Violet" (Station@1303)` и значением-множеством `(TreeSet@1367, size=1)`, содержащим ссылку на `"Fourth" (Station@1216)`.

---

Код в методе `addConnection` можно было бы переписать:

- с использованием классического цикла и "нового" метода [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), который возвращает ссылку на значение для данного ключа (если ключ не добавлен в мапу, будет создан новый экземпляр `Map.Entry` с пустым контейнером `TreeSet`)

```java
public void addConnection(List<Station> stations) {
    // создаём множество-кеш на основе входного списка
    Set<Station> exceptCurrent = new HashSet<>(stations);
    for (Station current : stations) {
        // убираем текущий элемент из кеша вместо его перегенерации
        exceptCurrent.remove(current);
        
        // копируем содержимое кеша в значение мапы
        connections.computeIfAbsent(current, key -> new TreeSet<>())
            .addAll(exceptCurrent);

        // возвращаем текущий элемент в кеш
        exceptCurrent.add(current);
    }
}
```

Вероятно, вместо входного *списка* `List<Station>` также следовало бы использовать *множество* `Set` в котором гарантированно не было бы дубликатов.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста, я его как раз немного улучшил :)